# Next.js + Paddle: CORS error on checkout.open

Tags: next.js, cors, payment-gateway, checkout

## Issue

I have a Next.js 13.4.1 app in which I'm implementing Paddle.js as the payment solution.

I'm on localhost and when I try to open the checkout, I get a 404 response with this CORS error:

> **Access to XMLHttpRequest at** 'https://sandbox-create-checkout.paddle.com/v2/checkout/product/undefined/?parentURL=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Fbilling&parent_url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Fbilling&referring_domain=localhost%3A4200%20%2F%20localhost%3A4200&display_mode=overlay&apple_pay_enabled=false&paddlejs-version=2.0.72&vendor=14017&checkout_initiated=1692529930415&popup=true&paddle_js=true&is_popup=true' **from origin** 'https://sandbox-buy.paddle.com' **has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

I went through the whole documentation again, but found nothing relevant:

- [paddle set-up checklist](https://developer.paddle.com/build/onboarding/set-up-checklist)
- [paddle build overlay checkout](https://developer.paddle.com/build/checkout/build-overlay-checkout)
- [paddle.js](https://developer.paddle.com/paddlejs/overview)
- [blog post on how to make the provider](https://medium.com/@deiucanta/how-to-integrate-paddle-js-with-next-js-280991461fce)

Do I need to configure next.js to add some headers to my request?

Is that even possible, as I'm importing the script that makes the call?

Do proxys help?

## Code

Paddle provider:

```
'use client'

import { createContext, useState } from 'react'
import Script from 'next/script'
import { getNodeEnv } from '@/utils/getNodeEnv'
import { vendor_id } from '@/helpers/APIs/paddle/config'

type PaddleContext = any

const PaddleContext = createContext<PaddleContext>(null)

type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode
}

const PaddleProvider: React.FC<Props> = ({ children }) => {
  
  const [paddle, setPaddle] = useState<any>(null)

  return (
    <PaddleContext.Provider value={paddle}>
      <Script
        src="https://cdn.paddle.com/paddle/paddle.js"
        onLoad={() => {
          if (getNodeEnv() !== 'prod') Paddle.Environment.set("sandbox")
          Paddle.Setup({
            vendor: Number(vendor_id),
          })
          setPaddle(Paddle)
        }}
      />
      { children }
    </PaddleContext.Provider>
  )
}

export { PaddleProvider, PaddleContext }
```

Component that uses the provider to open an overlay checkout:

```
const OfferOption: React.FC<Props> = ({ offer }) => {

  const paddle = usePaddleContext()

  const openCheckout = (price_id: string) => {
    paddle.Checkout.open({
      settings: {
        theme: 'dark'
      },
      items: [
        {
          price_id,
          quantity: 1
        }
      ]
    })
  }

  return (
    <button
      type='button'
      onClick={() => openCheckout(offer.price_id)}
...
```

Paddle global to get rid of the typescript issue:

```
declare global {
  const Paddle: any
}

export {}
```

Comment: It sounds like you don't understand what a CORS error is. Here's a link that you may find useful: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2021/08/02/fix-common-problems-cors .  It describes what causes the CORS error and gives ideas on how to go about fixing the underlying problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change localhost to another name, for example app.localtest.me if you have vite

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: do you mean like setting up a proxy or something?

Comment: There's a local test here, right? I had the same problem and changed my local hostname and it worked fine

Comment: I've checked out Vite and see what you mean, I'm not using it tho, so I guess reverse proxy it is, and I don't know much about proxys - time to learn...